# Why won't favicon load when HTML document is created with document.write()?

Tags: javascript, html, favicon

This simple HTML document contains a hyperlink with both an href attribute and an onclick attribute.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://byui-cse.github.io/cse111-course/site/icon.png">
    <script src="proto.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Load the <a href="sample.py" onclick="loadSample(event)">sample</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks the hyperlink, the onclick event handler from proto.js does the following:

1. Dynamically creates a string of HTML
2. Calls window.open() to open a new tab
3. Gets the document of the new tab
4. Calls doc.open()
5. Calls doc.write() to write the dynamic HTML into the new tab
6. Calls doc.close()

```
"use strict";

function loadSample(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const html =
['<!DOCTYPE html>',
'<html lang="en">',
'<head>',
'    <meta charset="UTF-8">',
'    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">',
'    <title>Sample</title>',
'    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://byui-cse.github.io/cse111-course/site/icon.png">',
'</head>',
'',
'<body>',
'<pre># Sample 1',
'import math',
'x = math.sqrt(63)</pre>',
'</body>',
'</html>'].join('\n');

    let win = window.open();
    let doc = win.document;
    doc.open();
    doc.write(html);
    doc.close();

    return false;
}
```

Everything seems to work fine, except the favicon will not display in the new tab. When I hold my mouse pointer over the new tab, a tooltip window opens with the text "Loading..."

I'm using the same favicon for both the original HTML document and the dynamic HTML document. Why won't the favicon display for the dynamic document?

Edit: the favicon displays for the dynamic document in Firefox, but not Chrome and Edge.